# A novel about humanity after the Earth has been devoured by foam

Tags: story-identification

I read a book in the early 2000s about a time after the Earth has been swallowed up by an assimilating foam... lattice... stuff. IIRC, scientists were working on it in a lab and dropped some, and because it's a chain reaction it dissolved... assimilated... ate everything it touched without stopping.

Enough of humanity got off (or already was off) the Earth to populate some of the rest of the solar system (notably some asteroids in the asteroid belt).

One notable technology was a ubiquitous glasses device (eerily like Google Glass) that would project a UI in front of the user to do computer stuff with.

John Conway's Game of Life (or some variation of it) was a significant feature of the story.

I think the main plot was the protagonist as part of a team that was tasked with returning to Earth.

> IIRC, they discover that the "foam" is actually intelligent and not-that-hostile. I think at the end of the book, humanity accepts the "foam" as a good way to die or be disposed of after death? Something like that...

Comment: Something to do with Grey Goo, that's pretty damn clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like [*Bloom*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?12573), a 1998 novel by [Wil McCarthy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wil_McCarthy). [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0345424654) review quoted below; see the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_(novel)) page for more detailed description.

> Mycora: technogenic life. Fast-reproducing, fast-mutating, and endlessly voracious. In the year 2106, these microscopic machine/creatures have escaped their creators to populate the inner solar system with a wild, deadly ecology all their own, pushing the tattered remnants of humanity out into the cold and dark of the outer planets. Even huddled beneath the ice of Jupiter's moons, protected by a defensive system known as the Immunity, survivors face the constant risk of mycospores finding their way to the warmth and brightness inside the habitats, resulting in a calamitous "bloom."
>
> But the human race still has a trick or two up its sleeves; in a ship specially designed to penetrate the deadly Mycosystem, seven astronauts are about to embark on mankind's boldest venture yet--the perilous journey home to infected Earth!
>
> Yet it is in these remote conditions, against a virtually omnipotent foe, that we discover how human nature plays the greatest role in humanity's future.

Comment: Yeah! That's it!